# Transfer local dictionary (.ths) file to heroku postgres instance

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I am using FTS in postgres, and I created a custom dictionary (.ths) file that I need to add to the following path (`/usr/local/share/postgresql/tsearch_data/`) in the heroku instance that is hosting my postgres DB. I see the AWS instance that heroku is hosting the DB on, but not sure how I can get the file from my local machine into that path, in order for postgres to properly use it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ping. Anyone have any ideas on this? Thanks!

Comment: Same. I opened a ticket with Heroku.

Comment: Just got a response from Heroku. Custom dictionaries are not supported, although I've seen questions about it from years ago.